# Blazor WASM Hosted with Authentication Breaks when upgrading to .net 6

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have a Blazor WASM Hosted with user Authentication that was running .net5 and I upgraded to .net 6.  However, I am now getting a 500 error when trying to click the login button.

I took a look at the following

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/upgrades/is4_v4_to_dis_v5/

I upgraded all projects to .net 6 and upgraded all NugetPackages to latest.
I updated the Namespaces which was only used on the DataContext

```
public class DataContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }
```

Here is my Server Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Register the Datacontext and Connection String
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            //Sets up the default Asp.net core Identity Screens - Use Identity Scaffolding to override defaults
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>( options =>
                    {
                        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

            //Associates the User to Context with Identity
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DataContext>( options =>
            {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
            });
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove(JwtClaimTypes.Role);

            //Adds authentication handler
            services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //AutoMigrates data
            dataContext.Database.Migrate();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSerilogIngestion();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

I added the DbSet Keys to the DataContext and I ran a migration using the following in the package manager console

```
add-migration UpdateToDuende
update-database
```

However every time I click the Login button i get a 500 with the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table dbo.keys appears to get deleted from the database during the upgrade. It also gets deleted (at least for me) the first time you run the application after the upgrade. A message does show up somewhere about this but it's hard to find. A backup of your database should have the dbo.keys table just script the create  from there and run it. run the app. run the script again and the problem , at least for me, went away.